# ckeditor not loading rich text editor by default

Tags: 7, nodes, blocks

I'm running CKEditor 7.x-1.19 with Drupal 7.80.

With "Default editor state" set to *Enabled*, and "Show the disable/enable rich text editor toggle" set to *Show*, my system is still loading the plain text window. I can then manually toggle to the rich text editor. I see this when creating new nodes or blocks, and also editing existing nodes and blocks - I think anywhere I'd expect the editor to load.

I'm running jQuery update 1.10 as the default version, and *Default jQuery Version* for administrative pages.

I've tried comparing this system to another where I don't see the same behavior, but I've not been able to determine a difference.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: What Input format is set as default? You need to set it as a priority by dragging it to top IIRC.

Comment: I do have full text as the primary format.

Comment: Are you sure? That one should appear by default then. Is your problem the text format or the ckeditor not loading when the correct text format loads? Add screenshots of your text editors list and what you see on the content edit pages